# Undefined name 'context'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined

Tags: flutter

GestureDetector(
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
context, // here i get the red line
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (_) => RestaurantScreen(restaurant: restaurant),
),
),

Comment: please fix your formatting and change tittle into a question form

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the context wherever you have the gestureDetector in order to be able to use the context.